# Simplifying (and/or bounding) a sum of product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

The question title is quite overused, but I hope I haven't duplicated something.

Can this be simplified?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p} \binom{q-1}{k-1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{b-1+k-1}\cdot \binom{m-1}{a-1+k-1}$$
**Edit**: All variables are non-negative integers, and $p \leq \min(m,n,q)$. Also,$m,n \geq q$.

I suspect that it might be possible because I was able to simplify a similar expression with two terms:
$$\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{m-1}{k-1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{a-1+k-1} = \binom{m+n-2}{a+n-2}$$

**Edit**: One of the reasons for simplifying this was to get a good upper bound on the expression; in the latter, it would just be when $a+p-2 = [\frac{m+n-2}{2}]$. Would it be possible to get an tight upper bound without simplifying it?

Comment: This can be answered algorithmically with Gosper's algorithm. If you have multiple similar questions it may be worth your while reading up on which sums it can handle so you can just throw them at a CAS (e.g. Wolfram Alpha) and then verify by induction.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I do have similar problems; I hope to do something similar for the general case, with more terms in a similar expression. I'll take a look at Gosper's algorithm, thanks.

Comment: what are $p,q,n,m,a,b$ ? all integers? all positive ? is $q \le p$ ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, how exactly should I go about using Gosper's algorithm? (Is there an implementation somewhere?)

Comment: I don't know what software you have access to. Commercial options certainly include Mathematica (NB included with the official Raspberry Pi distro, and behind the Wolfram Alpha website), Matlab, and Macsyma; free options include Maxima, and [Sage provides it by calling Maxima](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/calculus/calculus.html). If you're really stuck I can see about sending you the implementation I did for my final year project at uni, but it doesn't have as powerful a parser as those projects so you have to do a bit of work to put the input in the right form.

Comment: I have Mathematica, and I tried using the Gosper's algorithm provided by the package here: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/progs.html , it left me with a 3_F_2 term though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosper's algorithm by hand:

Our term is $$t(k) = \binom{q-1}{k-1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{b-1+k-1}\cdot \binom{m-1}{a-1+k-1}$$ so $$\frac{t(k+1)}{t(k)} = \frac{(q-k)(n-k-b+1)(m-a-k+1)}{k(b+k-1)(a+k-1)}$$
The numerator and denominator are both in linear factors already and none of them differ by a constant integer, so we seek a polynomial $s(k)$ such that $$1 = (q-k)(n-k-b+1)(m-a-k+1)s(k+1) - (k-1)(b+k-2)(a+k-2)s(k)$$
If the leading term of $s(k)$ is $\alpha_i k^i$, the leading term of the RHS is $-2 \alpha_i k^{3+i}$, so the RHS can't possibly be a constant polynomial. Therefore there is no solution, and Gosper's algorithm tells us that the sum does not have a closed form as a hypergeometric term.

Comment: Oh well then, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are entering the world of hypergeometric functions and I do not think that this is a simplification since moreover these functions corresponds to infinite summations.

To give you a taste of it, this would write
$$\binom{m-1}{a-1} \binom{n-1}{b-1} \, _3F_2(a-m,b-n,1-q;a,b;-1)-$$ $$\binom{q-1}{p}
   \binom{m-1}{a+p-1} \binom{n-1}{b+p-1} \, _4F_3(1,a-m+p,b-n+p,p-q+1;p+1,a+p,b+p;-1)$$

If $p=q$, the result is
$$\binom{m-1}{a-1} \binom{n-1}{b-1} \, _3F_2(a-m,b-n,1-q;a,b;-1)$$ and now, I am stuck !

Comment: Yes, but I can get the simpler case in terms of hypergeometric functions as well, and that does have a simplified form. So I don't think this would rule out a possible simplification.

Comment: @SS_C4. Without any relation between $a,b,m,n,p,q)$ it could be hard ! If there is any, just precise.

Comment: Yes, I'm don't think there would be any, so an upper bound would probably be my best bet at getting on with my work.

Comment: Though, if it helps, you can have $p=q$, and the other conditions in the edit I made a while ago.

Comment: @SS_C4. I shall work the problem tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.